# How does the U.S. government view Bitcoin? Is it money?

Tags: currencies, legal, government, usa

How does the U.S. government view Bitcoin?  Is it a currency, a commodity, or something else?

Comment: https://www.irs.gov/uac/Newsroom/IRS-Virtual-Currency-Guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The U.S. government views Bitcoin as a commodity, kind of like gold.

If you buy Bitcoin at one price in dollars, and sell it at a higher price in dollars, you will have a gain (in dollars), that you will have to pay tax on.

If you buy some Bitcoin (using dollars), and then use the Bitcoin to buy a car, you have made a "two stage" purchase of a car. (If you then re-sell the car for dollars, you may have a taxable gain if the dollars you receive are more than the dollars you used to buy the Bitcoin that you used to buy the car.

Comment: Would I have to pay sales tax on the car?

Comment: @Jesse: Consult your tax accountant. You're not a car dealer so the answer may be "technically yes, but the state won't chase you." That was actually my experience with a "use" tax. I filed and paid $24 (6% of $400), and the state of Connecticut sent it back to me.